# Python break the command line, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I just want to launch my program written in C++ from a Python script. 
I wrote the following script:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['l:\Proj\Silium.exe', '--AddWatch c:\fff.txt'])
```

But to my c++ application the parameter `"--AddWatch c:\fff.txt"` arrives without hyphens - it arrives as `"AddWatch c:\fff.txt"`. So my program doesn't work.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

UPD: thx for comments - yours answer helps!

Comment: Have you tried breaking them at each space so it looks like this. `subprocess.call(['l:\Proj\Silium.exe', '--AddWatch', 'c:\fff.txt'])`

Comment: you should probably use raw strings in this case as well: `r'l:\Proj\Silium.exe'`, (note the `r` prefix on the string,) otherwise python interprets your backslashes as escape sequences, which isn't what you want.

Comment: To be clear, others of us can't tell with certainty what a correct answer is because we don't know how your `Silium.exe` *expects* to be called. If you would call `Silium.exe --AddWatch c:\fff.txt`, then it should be `['Silium.exe', '--AddWatch', 'c:\\ff.txt']`; if you would call `Silium.exe "--AddWatch c:\fff.txt"` at `cmd.exe`, then it would be `['Silium.exe', '--AddWatch c:\\ff.txt']`. (`'\\'` is the same as `r'\'`). As its author, you're the only person here who knows what command-line format `Silium.exe` wants; everyone else is just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explain the issue and the solution.
I need to launch my application in the following way:

```
l:\Proj\Silium.exe --AddWatch c:\fff.txt
```

When I tried to do this using some hint from internet:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['l:\Proj\Silium.exe', '--AddWatch c:\fff.txt'])
```

the key "--AddWatch" arrives to my program without hyphens - like "AddWatch".

The solution is quite simple:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['l:\Proj\Silium.exe', '--AddCMakeWatch', 'c:\fff.txt',])
```

And issue gone away.

P.S.: its very strange that my initial code didnt work, I dont have any idea why python corrupt the command line, I think it is the python bug.

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes ('\") in regular strings.  Otherwise they could be interpreted as escape sequences that mean something else.  Such as `'\f'`, which translates into the form-feed character.  See [String and Byte Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for more information.  Also, Python didn't corrupt the command line, your initial attempt didn't work because you had `--AddCMakeWatch` and `c:\fff.txt` together in a single string which will get passed as a single parameter, not two args as required by the program. :-)